# jqm panel stops opening after refresh to the page (edited)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.3.1 panels. I have two panels (one on the left, one on the right) and to open my panels there are buttons and at the same time swipe events. Everything is working fine if the user doesn't refresh the page. If the user refreshes the page he can open the panel at that page but when he clicks to a link on the panel and routes to another page he can't open the panels any more (swipe or button both of them doesn't work). But if I refresh the page again it again starts to work just for one time. By the way I am using ajax for transitions in jqm. I couldn't find out why. Am I missing something in the usage of panels. Here is html;

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" class="panel" data-display="push" data-position="left" data-theme="a" class="ui-response">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="search" name="password" id="search" value="" placeholder="search"/>
</div>
<a data-role="button" href="home">home</a>

<a data-role="button" href="settings">settings</a>
<button id="signOutButton">sign out</button>
</div><!--Left Panel-->                <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel"   class="panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="a" class="ui-responsive">
</div><!--Right Panel-->
        <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>header</h1>
<button id="openLeftPanel">open</button>
<button id="openRightPanel">open</button>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content"
           <p>this is home</p>

        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
```

And here is my js;

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
//Opening panels with swipe, if any open don't open the panel (avoid closing swipe to open other panel)
//Catch swipes


      $( document ).on( 'swipeleft swiperight', function( evt ) {
            if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( 'panel' ) !== 'open' ) {
                if ( evt.type === 'swipeleft'  ) {
                    $( '#right-panel').panel( 'open' );
                } else if ( evt.type === 'swiperight' ) {
                    $( '#left-panel').panel( 'open' );
                }
            }
        });


    $(document).on('click tap', function(evt){
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

        var target = evt.target;
        var targetId = target.getAttribute('id');
        //Sign Out
       if(targetId === 'signOutButton'){
            window.authFunctions.deleteCookie('apiKey');
            window.location.replace('/');
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(targetId === 'openLeftPanel'){
            $('#left-panel').panel('open');
        }
        else if(targetId === 'openRightPanel'){
            $('#right-panel').panel('open');
        }

        });
```

sorry if the code is looking not pretty thats because I am using laravel's blade to create these pages on the server side.

Thanks in advance.

## **EDIT**

When trying it I recognized that; when I click on open panel button after it starts not working, it opens previous page's panel rather than active page's panel. I used previous page button on browser and saw that it is controlling previous page's panel. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Remove `pageinit` binding. It fires once and that's why they don't work again.

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved the problem. That was happening because previous pages were in cache. I started to remove previous pages. on page hide.

this is the code I used to solve;

 $(document).on('pagehide', function(event, ui){
        var page = $(event.target);
            page.remove();
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('pagehide', function(event, ui){
    var page = $(event.target);
        page.remove();
});
```

This code solved my problem by removing page that is going to hide.

Comment: I have no idea why, but it worked for me as well. Thanks :)